# Regarding creating a data set in accordance with a given data format

Tags: r

I am learning to use topicmodels package and R as well, and explored one of its example data set by using

> > str(testdata)
> >
> > 'data.frame':   3104 obs. of  5 variables:
> >
> > $ Article_ID: int  41246 41257 41268 41279 41290 41302 41314 41333 41344 41355 ...
> >
> > $ Date      : chr  "1-Jan-96" "2-Jan-96" "3-Jan-96" "4-Jan-96" ...
> >
> > $ Title     : chr  "Nation's Smaller Jails Struggle To Cope With Surge in Inmates" "FEDERAL IMPASSE SADDLING STATES WITH INDECISION" "Long, Costly Prelude Does Little To Alter Plot of Presidential Race" "Top Leader of the Bosnian Serbs Now Under Attack From Within" ...
> >
> > $ Subject   : chr  "Jails overwhelmed with hardened criminals" "Federal budget impasse affect on states" "Contenders for 1996 Presedential elections" "Bosnian Serb leader criticized from within" ...
> >
> > $ Topic.Code: int  12 20 20 19 1 19 1 1 20 15 ...

If I want to create a data set according to the above format in R, how to do that?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question... the data set is right there.  `head(testdata)` will show you its first few rows.  If you're wanting to see its string representation, `?dput`. Or you can write it out to disk with `write.table`.

Comment: @user288609: Do you now know enough about SO and R that you can either clarify your question, accept my answer, or delete your question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`test.data` is a data.frame, one of the few fundamental R objects. You should probably start here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf.

Some functions for creating data.frames are `data.frame`, `read.table`, `read.csv`. For each of these you can access their documentation by typing `?data.frame` for example. Good luck.